# SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'

Tags: php, javascript, html

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $("#tableMain").on("click", "a", function() {
  var ptsID = $(this).closest("tr").find("td:first").text();
  <?php
    $sql_var = "SELECT * FROM registros WHERE Id = 1";
    $result_var = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_var);
    $data = $result_var->fetch_assoc();
    var_dump($data);                                                        
  ?>
  });
</script>
```

La consola da el error:

> SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'

Lo genera en el `var_dump($data);` ya que al comentar esa línea el error desaparece.

`tableMain` es el `Id` de una `table`.
En `sql_var` luego reemplazo el "1" por `ptsID`.

Alguna sugerencia? Muchas gracias.

Comment: La respuesta corta es: **con `ajax`**. Debes tener presente que `PHP` se compila en el servidor, el resultado de dicho proceso es devuelto al navegador el cual compila y ejecuta `JS`. En otras palabras, no puedes pasarle a `PHP` el `id` así, ya que esa parte del código ya se ejecuto.

Comment: Estás mezclando php con javascript, para pasar datos de una a otra se utiliza el formato `json`. Tenés la función `json_encode($var)` de php como para resolverlo.

Comment: Lo más simple es usar Ajax para esto. Por ejemplo, desde el cliente (Javascript) mandas el `ID` al servidor (PHP)  el cual hace la consulta y devuelve de nuevo los datos al cliente (como un JSON, como HTML, como texto o como lo quieras)  y en el cliente actualizas lo que quieras con esos datos o los muestras donde quieras. Revisa aquí mismo varios ejemplos de Ajax.